# Perl - call scripts from another script with relative path

Tags: perl

I have Perl script that call other Perl scripts, I use this line for that :

```
system($^X, "script.pl", @ARGV);
```

All scripts exists on same folder but I want to call the main one from another folder, meaning scripts are under D:\TEST\Perl but I open command line from C:\ and call the main one from this location.

Probably a Silly question, but how can I call the child scripts that their location is relative to the main one?
Do I really need to use module for that? Which one?

Comment: you could use `chdir` first?

Comment: I think you need `FindBin`. But I also think you might have an `XY problem`.

Comment: What is wrong with listing callable scripts with their full path in one place in your program (using `FindBin` for the "main" one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [FindBin](https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin) module

```
use FindBin '$Bin'; # $Bin will contain the directory containing the executable file

# Then, later in your code
system($^X, "$Bin/script.pl", @ARGV);
```

Comment: `$RealBin` is the same as `$Bin`, except it also works if someone creates a symlink to the script. `$RealBin` should therefore be used instead of `$Bin`.

Comment: @ikegami I agree it's worth pointing out the difference between `$Bin` and `$RealBin`. I think that we don't know enough about the situation here to say which is best to use.

Comment: That makes no sense. `$RealBin` *adds* support for symbolic links without taking anything away, so `$RealBin` is always the best to use.